# Unique ID (Might be Binary or something)

Tags: identifier

// Okay originally people do their IDs for stuff like this:

```
var Item1 = 0;
var Item2 = 1;
var Item3 = 2;
var Item4 = 3;
var Item5 = 4;
```

// ... and so on.

// Then create more variables for their checks like:

```
var HasItem1 = false;
var HasItem2 = false;
var HasItem3 = false;
var HasItem4 = false;
var HasItem5 = false;
```

// Then somewhere in their code set the items to true if they want the user or player to // have the item, but that's alot of variables.

// Instead I wanted to do something like this:

```
var Item1 = 1;
var Item2 = 2;
var Item3 = 4;
var Item4 = 8;
var Item5 = 16;

var HasItems = 0; // 0 = no items added.
```

// The somewhere in my code:

```
HasItems = Item1 + Item3 + Item4; // 1 + 4 + 8 = 13
```

// But can't find a way to check if the player has Item3 for example.

```
if(HasItems != 0 && (HasItems & Item3) != -1) { // It was something like this.
    // Has the item we're looking for.
}
```

// Seen the ID system I'm talking about before, I forget where.
// Anyone know about this system of IDs?

// !!!EDIT!!!
http://blog.millermedeiros.com/using-integers-to-store-multiple-boolean-values/

Example:

```
[code]
var Item1 = (1 << 1);
var Item2 = (1 << 2);
var Item3 = (1 << 3);
var Item4 = (1 << 4);
var Item5 = (1 << 5);

var Items = (Item1 | Item3 | Item4);

if(Items & Item1) {
print("true 1");
} 
else {
print("false 1");
}

if(Items & Item2) {
print("true 2");
} 
else {
print("false 2");
}

if(Items & Item3) {
print("true 3");
} 
else {
print("false 3");
}

if(Items & Item4) {
print("true 4");
} 
else {
print("false 4");
}

if(Items & Item5) {
print("true 5");
} 
else {
print("false 5");
}
[/code]
```

Output:

```
true 1
false 2
true 3
true 4
false 5
```

Thank you all for your responses, I searched bitwise and walla.
Special thanks to winterblood!
For your concern, I know it only supports a limited amount of values, this is meant for small systems.

Comment: You have the overall premise of a bitwise permission system, but it cannot work with decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for 1 bit can be done with the following code:
`(HasItems & (1 << itemNumber)) != 0`
where `itemNumber` is number of item, starting at 0.

Also, this may be more universal and convenient:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx

Comment: @winterblood from the example, there is only powers of 2.

Comment: Yeah, acted without thinking, thus I deleted my original comment.

Comment: The OP should also know that this system is generally limited to a max ownership of 32 items within the number though (unless this is programmed for a 64 bit system, in which case 64 is the limit).

Comment: winterblood

This system makes it so the IDs can't add into themselves:
Item1 = 1
Item1 + Item1 = 2; // New ID.
Item1 + Item2 = 3; 
Item2 + Item2 = 4; // New ID.
Item1 + Item3 = 5; 
Item2 + Item3 = 6;
Item1 + Item2 + Item3 = 7;
Item3 + Item3 = 8; // New ID.

// Get it?

Comment: @user2893193 Bitwise systems cannot handle multiples of the same id. You are going to have to resort to a more conventional associative array type thing if you need to handle more than on/off toggling of an id.

Comment: @Sarge Borsch - Anyways that did not work at all, only Item2 came true, and Item2 wasn't even one of the ones I added.

Comment: @user2893193 You need to begin your indexing from 0 for the provided code to work, because `1 << 0 === 1`, `1 << 1 === 2`, `1 << 2 === 4` etc. but as I said above, it can't handle multiples of the same item.